# Is there a lightweight CMS/data-sets management library for PHP?

Tags: php, content-management-system

Currently I am adding on to an existing PHP application, and have to add new type of data entities and relationships. I am wondering if there are any lightweight CMS library for PHP - not full fledged framework such as WordPress, Drupal, ExpressionEngine or even framework such as CodeIgniter or Kohana, but just something which

1. Manages a set of database tables and fields
2. Automate grabbing of records through SQL and/or setting of variables
3. Displaying of content
4. Administration of content

The idea is that I just have to include the library and I don't have to re-code from ground up all the essential tasks of a CMS. The key is that it have to work with an already completed application (which, unfortunately, is commercial and not modular in design) Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Perahps SQL Maestro can help you : see [this](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/firebird/phpgenerator/)